# Adding a dataset at index / Replacing a DataSet

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to remove an entry and then fill the gap at that index by shifting all entries above that index.
(The adapter that shows data in graph fetches value from graph.Not any separate `ArrayList` maintained.)
Currently I managed to do it this way:

```
  final ArrayList<Entry> newEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mDataSet.getEntryCount()-1; i++) {
                if(i>=position){
                    newEntries.add(i,new Entry(i,mDataSet.getEntryForIndex(i+1).getY()));
                }else{
                    newEntries.add(i,new Entry(i,mDataSet.getEntryForIndex(i).getY()));
                }
            }
            final LineDataSet newDataSet= new LineDataSet(newEntries,mDataSet.getLabel());
            mChart.getLineData().removeDataSet(mDataSet);
            mChart.getLineData().addDataSet(newDataSet);
            mDataSet=newDataSet;
```

But the new dataset is added after the previous ones.Is there a way to replace a dataset or add dataset at index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I managed to replace datasets by

```
mChart.getLineData().getDataSets().set(mChart.getLineData().getIndexOfDataSet(mDataSet),newDataSet);
```